# Blogs object on Shopify checkout page is null

Tags: shopify, liquid, liquid-layout

Hi I am Shopify plus user. I want to add a blogs slider in footer of checkout page.I tried with just `blogs.news.articles`. But not able to loop through it as the blogs object return null on checkout page.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure if you have access to the standard object in the checkout layout. Someone will need to confirm this.

Comment: Who could confirm this?

Comment: just test it. If you try to get page/product/collection title and you can't, you will have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Blogs are a global object but probably cannot be used in checkout as that is just too out there for comprehension.